# C++ - MPIR: Fastest Log Function?

Tags: c++

MPIR is a really good library that I am currently using in C++ to deal with large numbers. Unfortunately, it does not have any log functions. Because of that, I am seeking a fast log function for MPIR's mpz_class.

We are all well aware of the fact that there are some log functions that are already provided in C++ (or should be), which are located in the Math header file (Math.h). Unfortunately, they can not handle big numbers, which is one of the many reasons why I am using MPIR library,

```
::mpz_class Log( ::mpz_class n ) {
    ::mpz_class ret;
    return ret;
};
```

There are some cases in which the log of n returns floating value. Hence, our log function must be able to return a floating value. If we were to do the Log of 15, it should return 1.17609125906.

Comment: Did you get success doing logarithm using MPFR ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another library [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/), which (I think) is built on top of MPIR and this *does* contain functions for logarithms.

Comment: Comparing the library MPIR with MPFR library, which one is faster?

Comment: Well, I think they're both rooted in GNU MP, so possibly similar(?) - maybe good to find some comparisons, but I don't know of anything. MPFR says it can be built "on top of" MPIR anyway.

Comment: @CLearner: Faster is complete up to your measurements. Nobody can say for sure unless they steal your computer and benchmark the final product for you.

Comment: @CLearner MPIR and MPFR have different purposes. MPIR provides Integer and Rational arithmetic (and very limited floating-point support). MPFR only provides floating point arithmetic. MPFR uses MPIR behind-the-scenes but it doesn't make any sense to compare their performance.

Comment: @RogerRowland Did you get success doing logarithm using MPFR ?

Comment: @user3891236 To be honest, I never tried it. When I answered this question, I was just pointing the OP to an alternative library. Maybe you should ping the questioner.